# How to use dynamic- height feature to be used

Tags: google-apps, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

i am writing a google gadget for gmail. i am new to gadgets.for a gadget , i wirte first an html page then converted it into Module for google gadget.i used this module spec

```
<Module>
    <ModulePrefs title="Cloud Factor Demo" scrolling="false"  description="Cloud Factor Demo Design" author="Ritesh Mehandiratta" author_email="..." author_location="Mountain View, CA">
        <Require feature="dynamic-height" />
        <Require feature="google.contentmatch"></Require>
    </ModulePrefs>
    <!-- Define the content type and display location. The settings
   "html" and "card" are required for all Gmail contextual gadgets. -->
    <Content type="html" view="card"><![CDATA[
```

but when i goto my gmail page this html is in scrolling mode. i want to make its height same as the height it take how to remove this scrolling ?? here is screenshot of scrolling 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, gadgets are 200 pixels high.  If you want to use dynamic height feature, follow the steps below,

add `<Require feature="dynamic-height" />` in ModulePrefs tag, which u already did. And whenever you feel, the height should be refreshed, call `gadgets.window.adjustHeight();`

example - If you want it to be done during page load,

```
<script>
function onPageLoaded() {
               gadgets.window.adjustHeight();
                }
</script>

<body onload="onPageLoaded()">
```

For more info, follow google developers link - https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/ui#Dyn_Height